# skip template if cookbook does not contain file

Tags: chef-infra

I wish to skip creation of a file if it doesn't exist on the cookbook.
example of current resource in use:

```
cookbook_file "#{filename}.txt" do
  source "#{filename}_#{node['hostname']}"
  ignore_failure true
end
```

`ignore_failure` works in this case, however it does display a big error on my chef run when triggered.

Is there a guard I could use in order to skip the resource altogether if the specific template doesn't exist? something like this:

```
//I just made this up to illustrate my point 
only_if { "#{Chef::CookbookFile[:cookbook_files]}".include?('#{filename}_#{node['hostname']}') }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something we really support. If you go digging in the [internal APIs](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/75f1d2c8836a10ca5d2e427df465111c5351b3b6/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb#L203) you can find ways to do it, but it's not a use case we encourage or support. What would be better is to set up a fallback template. Something like `source ["#{filename}_#{node['hostname']}.erb", "#{filename}_default.erb"]` or similar so if the per-hostname template isn't found, it uses the default one (which could just be empty).

Comment: the alternative is even better, I didn't know about this feature! thanks